# merge 2 images with node.js and gm

Tags: javascript, node.js, png, graphicsmagick

I want to merge 2 images using node.js an gm for node. In fact I want to place one smaller image on cordinates x,y on a larger image.

I've allraedy someting working with append() but i cannot choose to put the second image above the first one

here's my js code of append.

```
gm('img/vector/test.svg').append('img/base/test.png').write('img/final/test.png', function(err, stdout, stderr, command){
            if (err){
                console.log('image conversion error!'); 
                console.log(err); 
                console.log(command);    
            }else{ 
                console.log('image converted with command :'); 
                console.log(command);
            } 
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This option creates a single image where the images in the original set are stacked top-to-bottom" says the [gm doc](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-append)

usually i would say take a look at [montage](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/montage.html), but the node-module does not seem to support that...

Comment: I finaly find a workarround using montage :
gm('img/base/'+baseFileName+'.png')
            .subCommand('montage')
            .texture('img/vector/svg-'+scorePercent+'.svg')
            .geometry(81, 81)
            .font('Arial', 18)
            .fill(textColor)
            .drawText(textPos, 60, textLabel)
            .write('img/final/'+baseFileName+'.png', function(...)